# Expand/Collapse div inside html table retrieving data from db

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, bootstrap-4

In an Basic HTML Table containing child rows, how to expand and collapse the Parent Row onClick of '+'.

Below is the script which I has been tried, where OnClick of '+' nothing happens onlt the sigh changes from '+' to '-' and also the child rows are rendered directly which should have hidden when it is in collapse mode.
I am fetching this Child Row Table data from my DB using PHP. Attached is the PHP Code, Script and DB data.

Can the same solution be applied on a datatable ?

PHP Code :

```
<?Php
 echo "<table>"; 
 echo "<thead>
   <tr>
    <th rowspan='2'></th>
    <th rowspan='2'>Departmental Activity</th>
    <th rowspan='2'>Complete<br>Report</th>
  </tr>

</thead>";                    
$count="SELECT id,department,authority FROM department";
 foreach ($dbo->query($count) as $row) 
{
    $sid='s'.$row['id'];
      echo "<tr >
      <td style='width:25px'>

           <div id='$sid' style='display:inline;width:25px' onclick=display_detail($row[id])> 
        +                                                                            
           </div>
     </td>
                                                                                <td>$row[department]</td>
    <td></td>
                                                                              </tr>";
                                                                        echo "<div style='display:none' id=$row[id]>
                                                                                <tr >
<td></td>
                                                                                <td><b>id</b> : $row[id]</td>
                                                                                <td><b>Abb. </b>: $row[authority]</td>
</tr>
<tr >
<td></td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</div>";
   }
 echo "</table>";
?>
```

JS:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function display_detail(id){

var sid='s'+id;
if( document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'inline' ){
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'; // Hide the details div
document.getElementById(sid).innerHTML = '+';  // Change the symbol to + 

}else {

document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = '#ffff00'; // Add different color to background
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';  // show the details
document.getElementById(sid).innerHTML = '-'; //Change the symbol to -

} // end of if else 
} // end of function

</script>
```

MySQL DB Data:

```
--
-- Database: `finalcms`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `department`
--

CREATE TABLE `department` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `department` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `authority` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `department`
--

INSERT INTO `department` (`id`, `department`, `authority`, `status`) VALUES
(35, 'Account', 'ACC', 1),
(36, 'Development', 'DEG', 1),
(37, 'Dispatch', 'DSP', 1);
```

Expecting the child data is only displayed onClick of expand and hidden when collapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could use Front end library like jQuery instead of plain JavaScript, You can reduce lines of script.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
  table.blueTable {
  border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.blueTable td, table.blueTable th {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 3px 2px;
}
table.blueTable tbody td {
  font-size: 13px;
}
table.blueTable thead {
  background: #1C6EA4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
}
table.blueTable thead th {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
}
table.blueTable thead th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
table.blueTable tbody tr.child {
  display: none;
  background: #D0E4F5;
}
</style>
<?php
$dbo = null;
try {
  $dbo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=finalcms;host=localhost', 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $ex->getMessage();
}

 echo "<table class=blueTable>"; 
 echo "<thead>
   <tr>
    <th rowspan='2'></th>
    <th rowspan='2'>Departmental Activity</th>
    <th rowspan='2'>Complete<br>Report</th>
  </tr>

</thead><tbody>";                    
$count="SELECT id,department,authority FROM department";
foreach ($dbo->query($count) as $row) 
{
    $sid='s'.$row['id'];
    echo "<tr>
        <td style='width:25px; text-align: center;'>
          <div class='sidbutton' id='$sid' style='display:inline;width:25px' onclick=display_detail($row[id])>+</div>
        </td>
        <td>$row[department]</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>";
    echo "<tr class='child ".$sid."child'>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><b>id</b> : $row[id]</td>
              <td><b>Abb. </b>: $row[authority]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='child ".$sid."child'>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>";
   }
 echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
<script language="JavaScript">
function display_detail(id){  

  var sid='s'+id;
  var sidbuttons = document.getElementsByClassName('sidbutton');
  for(i = 0; i < sidbuttons.length; i++) {
    if(sidbuttons[i].id == sid){
      if(sidbuttons[i].classList.contains('bopen')){
        sidbuttons[i].innerHTML = '+';
        sidbuttons[i].classList.remove('bopen');
      }else{
        sidbuttons[i].innerHTML = '-';
        sidbuttons[i].classList.add('bopen');    
      }      
    }else{
      if(!sidbuttons[i].classList.contains('bopen'))
        sidbuttons[i].innerHTML = '+';      
    }
  }

  var childrows = document.getElementsByClassName('child');
  for(i = 0; i < childrows.length; i++) {
    if(childrows[i].classList.contains(sid+'child')){
      if( childrows[i].classList.contains('copen') ){
        childrows[i].style.display = 'none';
        childrows[i].classList.remove('copen');
      }
      else{
        childrows[i].style.display = 'table-row';
        childrows[i].classList.add('copen'); 
      }
    }else{
      if(!childrows[i].classList.contains('copen'))  
        childrows[i].style.display = 'none';      
    }  
  }  

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. JQuery script is working fine, When we click on + sign it expands the details to view the child rows, but when we click on + sign of any other row, it is collapses the child row which was expanded above and this should not happen. So until we do not collapse the row using '-', it should stay in expanded state. Also currently the collapse does not work for the script you shared.

Comment: @Snehal Yeah. I was coded as per normal user scenario..and your's is something strange. I edited some scripts and added some classes to manage custom collapse here. Update using this code to make effective in your code and more over i added necessary CSS, class and removed unwanted div from  your previous code.(NB: Try to do Same logic if you integrated jQuery ).

Comment: Thank you for response,It is working perfectly fine.